# Escape message to logger

Tags: bash, logging, escaping

I have a bash script where I want to log arguments and outputs to the local syslog. For this I use logger.

```
logger -p local0.notice -t TagToUse "Message to log"
```

The thing is that I want to log the output of `$@` which may contain `-u` which is an option of logger. If that occurs I always get an error message `logger: socket <Value of $@>: No such file or directory` which means that logger still tries to parse the logging message for options. Is there a way to escape the logging message or to mark the message as string to not parse anything in it?

Edit:
Trying to log via STDIN results in the same error message

```
echo "$@" > logger -p local0.notice -t TagToUse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--` to signal that `logger` should stop looking for options among the remaining arguments.

```
logger -p local0.notice -t TagToUse -- "$@"
```

You might want to use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` to provide a *single* argument containing the log message.